# Understanding the details of this Python Code

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The task is to load the iris data set from sklearn and then make some plots. I wish to understand what each command is doing.

> from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

**Q1** Is load_iris a function in sklearn?

> data = load_iris()

**Q2**  Now I believe this load_iris function is returning some output which we are storing as data. What exactly is the output of load_iris()? type etc?

> df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

**Q3** Now we are storing this as a dataframe. but what is data.data and data.feature_names

> df['target_names'] = [data.target_names[i] for i in data.target]

**Q4** I don't understand the right hand side of the above code
Need help with Questions 1,2,3 and 4. I tried looking at the Scikit documentation but didn't understand it. Also this code is from an online course on edx but they didn't explain the code.

Comment: You need to look into Python documentation. Especially list comprehension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Discover the power of intercativity of Jupyter/iPython.

I'm using iPython in this example.

> **Q1** Is load_iris a function in sklearn?

```
In [33]: type(load_iris)
Out[33]: function
```

> **Q2** Now I believe this load_iris function is returning some output
>   which we are storing as data. What exactly is the output of
>   load_iris()? type etc?

Docstring - is very helpful:

```
In [34]: load_iris?
Signature: load_iris(return_X_y=False)
Docstring:
Load and return the iris dataset (classification).

The iris dataset is a classic and very easy multi-class classification
dataset.

=================   ==============
Classes                          3
Samples per class               50
Samples total                  150
Dimensionality                   4
Features            real, positive
=================   ==============

Read more in the :ref:`User Guide <datasets>`.

Parameters
----------
return_X_y : boolean, default=False.
    If True, returns ``(data, target)`` instead of a Bunch object. See
    below for more information about the `data` and `target` object.

    .. versionadded:: 0.18

Returns
-------
data : Bunch
    Dictionary-like object, the interesting attributes are:
    'data', the data to learn, 'target', the classification labels,
    'target_names', the meaning of the labels, 'feature_names', the
    meaning of the features, and 'DESCR', the
    full description of the dataset.

(data, target) : tuple if ``return_X_y`` is True
...
```

print description:

```
In [51]: print(data.DESCR)
Iris Plants Database
====================

Notes
-----
Data Set Characteristics:
    :Number of Instances: 150 (50 in each of three classes)
    :Number of Attributes: 4 numeric, predictive attributes and the class
...
```

> **Q3** Now we are storing this as a dataframe. but what is data.data and data.feature_names

```
In [37]: type(data.data)
Out[37]: numpy.ndarray

In [88]: data.data.shape
Out[88]: (150, 4)

In [38]: df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

In [39]: pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 10)

In [40]: df
Out[40]:
     sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)
0                  5.1               3.5                1.4               0.2
1                  4.9               3.0                1.4               0.2
2                  4.7               3.2                1.3               0.2
3                  4.6               3.1                1.5               0.2
4                  5.0               3.6                1.4               0.2
..                 ...               ...                ...               ...
145                6.7               3.0                5.2               2.3
146                6.3               2.5                5.0               1.9
147                6.5               3.0                5.2               2.0
148                6.2               3.4                5.4               2.3
149                5.9               3.0                5.1               1.8

[150 rows x 4 columns]

In [41]: df.columns
Out[41]: Index(['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)'], dtype='object')

In [42]: data.feature_names
Out[42]:
['sepal length (cm)',
 'sepal width (cm)',
 'petal length (cm)',
 'petal width (cm)']
```

> **Q4** I don't understand the right hand side of the above code Need help with Questions 1,2,3 and 4. I tried looking at the Scikit
>   documentation but didn't understand it. Also this code is from an
>   online course on edx but they didn't explain the code.

Execute the code and check the result - usually it's easy to see what has happened. BTW, i'd use Numpy for this step:

```
In [49]: df['target_names'] = np.take(data.target_names, data.target)

In [50]: df
Out[50]:
     sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm) target_names
0                  5.1               3.5                1.4               0.2       setosa
1                  4.9               3.0                1.4               0.2       setosa
2                  4.7               3.2                1.3               0.2       setosa
3                  4.6               3.1                1.5               0.2       setosa
4                  5.0               3.6                1.4               0.2       setosa
..                 ...               ...                ...               ...          ...
145                6.7               3.0                5.2               2.3    virginica
146                6.3               2.5                5.0               1.9    virginica
147                6.5               3.0                5.2               2.0    virginica
148                6.2               3.4                5.4               2.3    virginica
149                5.9               3.0                5.1               1.8    virginica

[150 rows x 5 columns]
```